# Retrive pdf's link from google drive and upload it on mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, google-drive-api, web-development-server

I want to create a website to provide PDF notes to students.
I am planning to upload pdf on my googledrive and want to serve those pdf using my website.
I am using MongoDb As Database and my plan is to read link of pdf from my google drive and want to save it on collection of mongodb so that it will render on my website dynamically.
Is there any convenient way to do this automatically rather than copy pasting each link.(because it will be a time draining stuff and we have to upload 1000 of pdfs).

If this method is not possible Please suggest me some better way to do this work using nodejs and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

If using Google Drive is not a must, I recommend you to use [MongoDB's GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). GridFS allows you to store documents that are higher than 16MB. In this way, you do not need to manage/update document links, because MongoDB will be already in charge of metadata and the document itself.

[image]

> - If your filesystem limits the number of files in a directory, you can use GridFS to store as many files as needed.
> - When you want to access information from portions of large files without having to load whole files into memory, you can use GridFS to recall sections of files without reading the entire file into memory.
> - When you want to keep your files and metadata automatically synced and deployed across a number of systems and facilities, you can use GridFS. When using geographically distributed replica sets, MongoDB can distribute files and their metadata automatically to a number of mongod instances and facilities.

[This tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/) might be the starting point.